# How to compile C++ programs in codeblocks for 32bit computers with the dual targets MinGw compiler

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw, codeblocks

I have downloaded the dual-target mingw compiler for C++11 (32bit and 64bits windows computers), But when i compile my program with codeblocks, mingw compile it for 64bits computers.. How to compile my program for 32bits computers ?

Here is the link of the MinGw version which i have downloaded : http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/

Thanks !

Comment: Does it work if you add `-m32`?

Comment: i had already try to add the -m32 but when i compile, it tell me so much errors...